# Passing pointer arguments to a double pointer argument

Tags: c++

I have a sequence of calls where the final call requires a double pointer. It seems that I am always getting a null pointer in the end. I have simplified this down a lot to the following. The final call is a library call that returns a pointer.

This is the simplified mess. The `foo` in `MainCaller` is always 0 even though I know (through the libraries testing methods) that the object does exist.

```
void MainCaller(){
    foo_t *foo;
    MiddleProcessor(foo);
    // foo results as 0
}

void MiddleProcessor(foo_t *foo){
  if(1){
    ProcessorA(foo);
  }else{
    ProcessorB(foo);
  }
}

void ProcessorA(foo_t *foo){
    FinalCall(&foo);
}

void FinalCall(foo_t **foo){
    *foo = some_lib_call();
    lib_call_test_is_good_foo(foo); // true :)
}
```

Comment: I feel like parameter types are missing in MiddleProcessor and ProcessorA, and it looks like you're passing the pointer by value.

Comment: I think you're right @Caninonos but I don't know what combos of `**` and `*&` and all that to use..

Comment: What is the return type of `some_lib_call()`?

Comment: It returns `foo*`

Comment: `if(1){` is always true, so for a minimal example you should just remove the conditionals and just do a call to `ProcessorA(foo);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are that you are passing the pointer by value and `FinalCall` never knows where the original lives.

These changes may help:

```
void MainCaller(){
    foo_t *foo;
    MiddleProcessor(&foo); // Passing the address of foo means foo can be overwritten
    // foo results as 0
}

void MiddleProcessor(foo_t **foo){
  if(1){
    ProcessorA(foo);
  }else{
    ProcessorB(foo);
  }
}

void ProcessorA(foo_t **foo){
    FinalCall(foo);
}

void FinalCall(foo_t **foo){
    *foo = some_lib_call();
    lib_call_test_is_good_foo(foo); // true :)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing `foo` in `FinalCall` has no effect on `foo` in `MainCaller`. They're different variables why should changing one change the other?

Instead you want something like this

```
void MainCaller(){
    foo_t *foo;
    foo = MiddleProcessor();
}

foo_t* MiddleProcessor(){
  if(1){
    return ProcessorA();
  }else{
    return ProcessorB();
  }
}

foo_t* ProcessorA(){
    foo_t* foo;
    FinalCall(&foo);
    return foo;
}

void FinalCall(foo_t **foo){
    *foo = some_lib_call();
    lib_call_test_is_good_foo(foo); // true :)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I cannot be changing the return values. My simplified example was exactly that - simplified.

Comment: This is a better design as it uses more pointers and less pointers to pointers.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify a parameter you need to pass by reference, which you can do with an explicit reference or a pointer. If the thing you want to change is a pointer, you need a reference to a pointer or a pointer to a pointer.